# Accessing many dataframes at the same row and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From the weather forecast service DWD you can download csv-like files containing the historical rainfall in a high-resolution grid (see everything here for example https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/hourly/radolan/historical/asc/). This data can be loaded into python using a simple dataframe as follows

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_location, delimiter=' ', skiprows=6, header=None, usecols=range(900), na_values=[-1])
```

In my application I want to observe various points over time (e.g. 2 years). The problem here is that in order to do so, I need to load each df into memory, but only access one value. This results either in a large RAM-usage (if I keep all files in memory) or many file-reading processes (if the files are loaded into memory on every access). To overcome this issue and make parallel computing easier, I want to extract lists of all values at a given row-column combination for all dataframes. Unfortunately I could not find an example on SO or elsewhere on how to do this efficiently. A simplified example is given below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfs = []
for i in range(1000):
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(900,900)))


for row in range(900):
    for column in range(900):
        extract all values at df[row, column] efficiently and save to file
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you convert the data files to binary format?  In one simple test:

- `np.loadtxt()` imported a 900x900 array in 0.264 sec (text format)
- `np.load()` imported the binary version in 0.0012 sec (binary format)
- 217x speedup

Parquet and feather (in pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html) ) are other high-performance storage options, and [dask](https://dask.org/) may be helpful for managing computations.

```
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from time import perf_counter

data_dir = Path('../../../Downloads/RW-201912') 
text_file = 'RW_20191231-2350.asc'
bin_file = 'test.npy'

# 1. read text file
start = perf_counter()
with open(data_dir / text_file, 'rt') as handle:
    x = np.loadtxt(handle, skiprows=6)
elapsed = perf_counter() - start
print(x.shape, round(elapsed, 4))

# 2. write binary file
start = perf_counter()
with open(data_dir / bin_file, 'wb') as fp:
    np.save(fp, x.astype(np.int8))
elapsed = perf_counter() - start
print(round(elapsed, 4))

# 3. read binary file
start = perf_counter()
with open(data_dir / bin_file, 'rb') as handle:
    y = np.load(handle)
elapsed = perf_counter() - start
print(y.shape, round(elapsed, 4))

(900, 900) 0.2661 # read text file
0.0026            # write binary file
(900, 900) 0.0009 # read binary file
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. This does accelerate the file reading. And I think I have been in a bit of a tunnel I believe as the second part of the question that I actually asked about can be achieved by combining the numpy matrices.